# How do I create an observable function in F#, based on an existing C# snippet?

Tags: c#, f#, reactive-programming, c#-to-f#

I am trying to convert the following code to F#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var y = Observable.Create<int>(x =>
        {
            x.OnNext(5);
            return (() => { });
        });

    y.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
}
```

tried the following :

```
let ob = Observable.Create<int>(fun x -> 
                                    x.OnNext(5)
                                    fun unit -> unit)
```

but no success. What should I be doing?

Comment: _"but no success"_ - what do you expect and what happened?

Comment: The last statement is the return value. `unit` is not a value, it is type. Try to replace it with empty sequence. Don't know if that will help to get it working.

Answer (score 6):

```ml
let observable = Observable.Create(fun (x: IObserver<_>) ->
  x.OnNext(5)
  Action(ignore))

observable.Subscribe(printfn "%d") |> ignore
```

Answer (score 6):

If your Observable cannot be cancelled (usually when it is synchronous) , it's more efficient to use the singleton `Disposable.Empty`

```
Observable.Create(fun (o : IObserver<_>) -> 
    o.OnNext(5)
    Disposable.Empty
)
```